Is it possible to draw percentile distribution graph in Excel?
Is it possible to draw a graph in MS Excel with reverse log X-axis for percentiles, so "ticks" on X-axis should be 90%, 99%, 99.9%, 99.99%, 99.999% and overall graph will look like this:

This type of chart is commonly used for visualizing latency measurements.
Reference image is produced using https://hdrhistogram.github.io/HdrHistogram/plotFiles.html

Calculate the percentile numbers, place them in a table and use the table as data for a graph?

@Hannu The main part of question is: how to make X-axis to look like that? It's proportional to 1 - (0.1^k)

Right, the obvious seems be to use that formula (or a variant of it) to find reasonable X-values (a list) for the table.

@AlexeiOsipov: You might try experimenting with the "Display Units", the "Logarithmic Scale" and the # decimal places for the labels. That's the only way I could get close...
